# HTTP POST with json - wrong parameters

Tags: java, json, post, http-post, httpclient

I'm trying to invoke a REST Service which accepts a json with the two parameters **param1** and **param2**, as below:

```
[{
"param1": "xxx",
"param2": "xxx"
}]
```

Following my code invoking MY_SERVICE_URL:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(MY_SERVICE_URL);        
String json = new String("[{\"param1\": \"" + "param1Value" + "\",\"param2\": \"" + "param2Value" + "\"}]");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String output = rd.readLine();
    System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("Output: " + output);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}

client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

The POST is failing because it's not recognizing the first parameter as valid: instead of reading **param1** it's considering the parameter **\"param1\"**

Any help is appreciated
Thanks
Simone

Comment: Hello Simone, please could you add in your question a snippet of the stacktrace? This is often of a great use to know what's going on and also to retrieve your question for people having the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet to create JSON for posting over your webservice/api. Hope it helps
Add the following reference too **import org.json.simple.JSONObject;**

```
JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
item.put("param1", "testValue1");
item.put("param2", 123);
item.put("param3", "testValue3");

String json = item.toString();
```

Comment: recheck your answer. the question was erroneously tagged c# what it appears to be targeting  java.

Comment: @Nkosi you are right, I wrongly put the c# tag, but we're talking about java. Please also consider I've also used some JSON utilities but the POST is always failing for above error

Comment: @Aditya I'm sorry but the code refers to java. I corrected the tag, thanks

Comment: @SimoneCeccolini kindly check the updated answer. Hope this will resolve your query.